# HttpWebRequest to server failing on some machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, http

I have 4 machines on the same network but two of them are failing when making a httpwebrequest to the same server. I noticed that the request looks a bit different on these machines. It contains extra "base" levels when I expand it in the VS breakpoint debugger.

Here is the request for a machine that WORKS:

[image]

And here it is for one that doesn't work:
[image]

Notice how many more base levels I have in the one that fails. Any idea of what could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting any exception. Catch System.Net.WebException  for your request and see what exception it is throwing.

Comment: The exception's status is just "ConnectFailure"

Comment: Are you using proxy ? Maybe firewall is blocking connection to those machine. Can you ping those machines from your machine ?

Comment: I can ping the server from the failing machines. It's not firewall. One weird thing is, when I turn on fiddler, the application works. It is able to connect to the server.

Comment: Looks like proxy issue. Fiddler changes your proxy settings when it starts and reverts them back when you close it. There is a setting in fiddler Tools / Fiddler Options which says something along the line of act as a system proxy and may be that is why it works when you open fiddler.